# How to generate submodules in a Typescript library project?

Tags: typescript, node-modules

I'm building a library project named ***br-store*** that I use in other projects with imports declarations like this one:

```
import { getAlarms } from "br-store"
```

In this case `getAlarms` is a exported function which is inside `src/store/alarm/actions`.

What I want to achieve now is to transpile my library so I'm able to use it anywhere else in such a way as this:

```
import { getAlarms } from "br-store/alarm/actions"
```

My project has the following folder structure:

```
./src/store/
├── alarm
│   ├── alarm-actions.ts
│   ├── alarm-constants.ts
│   ├── alarm-reducer.ts
│   └── index.ts
|__ index.ts
......
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./bin",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "spec/*",
    "tests/*",
    "integration/",
    "node_modules/"
  ]
}
```

**./src/store/index.ts:**

```
export * from './alarm'
.....
```

**/src/store/alarm/index.ts**

```
export * from './alarm-actions'
export * from './alarm-reducer'
```

Answer (score -1):

I generally suggest avoiding deep linking.

When user depends on your internal folder structure, any folder change would be a breaking change to the user. It makes your library unnecessarily rigid.

If you manually manage the redirects:

```
// <project-root>/alarm/actions.js`
export * from '../dist/alarm/actions'
```

That might be ok because you still have reasonable control and freedom to do your things. But it is a manual step.

If you really want to make `tsc` to do it automatically for you, you can set `outDir: ".."` and have it dump all your js files to the root of your project.

But I think you won't be happy to see your project becomes a dumping ground.